# Подскажите как сделать % наценку сразу на все товары

Tags: python

Подскажите как сделать % наценку сразу на все товары.
Изменения цены это так выполняется:

```
shop = {
    "мучное": {
        "хлеб": 200
    },
    "молочное":{
        "молоко":50
    },
    "мясное": {
        "говядина":500
    }
}

def update_price(user_group, products, news_price,shop=shop):
    shop[user_group][products] += news_price
    return shop
                
update_price(user_group, products, news_price)

def print_all_products(shop=shop):
    for group, array in shop.items():
        print ("Раздел: " + group)
        for product, price in array.items():
            print(product + " - " + str(price))
print_all_products()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Процент добавляется через умножение

```
def update_percent(persent, shop=shop):
    for group in shop.keys():
        for products in shop[group].keys():
            shop[group][products] *= 1 + persent/100



update_percent(5)
```